# How can I find out the machine names of user variables?

Tags: theming, users

I'm creating a custom user profile page and I know how to print certain items attached to the user like

```
$user_profile['user_picture']
```

but I don't know the names of any of the other fields. Is there a way that I can view a list of user profile field machine names?

Comment: [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel), [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) or simply [read them](https://www.drupal.org/files/Screen%20Shot%202013-02-18%20at%204.36.15%20PM.png) from configuration page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the user variables are located in `configuration->People->Account Settings->Manage Fields`. So simply look at them over there.